# RSelenium Text Extraction not Working in Loop

Tags: r, for-loop, web-scraping, rselenium

I am trying to extract text from a database of cases from this Government website -  https://www.te.gob.mx/buscador/ - using RSelenium.

I have managed to get RSelenium to pull the text I am interested in and store it in a dataframe manually, however, I want this to iterate automatically via a `for loop`

The browser goes to a website that looks like this:[image: Sample Page from MX Website]

It then clicks on the first link on the site under "Resumen" which opens up a page that looks like this:[image: Sample Resumen Subpage]

I'm extracting some of the text from each of these "Resumen" subpages and storing them in a dataframe.

Here's what my code looks like:

```
setwd("C:/Users/ohenr/Dropbox/10-19 Research Projects/16 R")
getwd()
pacman::p_load(rvest, tidyverse, stringr, RSelenium, data.table) #loads all the packages in one command

url <- "https://www.te.gob.mx/buscador"


# Setting up the remote driver

remDr <- remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "192.168.99.100", port = 4445L,
                       browserName = "firefox")

# Input this into the terminal to start the firefox image in docker
# docker run -d -p 4445:4444 selenium/standalone-firefox:2.53.0

# Open the remote Driver (open firefox in R Selenium)
remDr$open()

# Navigating throught the mx resumen website
remDr$navigate(url)

# Click the regions on the left side of the webpage

region_lists <- remDr$findElements(using = "css selector", ".salas-tree")

region_lists[[1]]$clickElement()

#List resumen elements from the first page
res <- remDr$findElements("css selector", "#resumenResultados")

# number of resumen on the first page
res_n <- length(res)

#build a dataframe that has that same number of observations
resumen.df <- data.frame(expediente = character(res_n),
                          entidad = character(res_n),
                          turno = character(res_n),
                          res_text = character(res_n),
                          stringsAsFactors = F)

for (j in 1:res_n) {

    res[[j]]$clickElement() # click on the jth resumen

    elements <- remDr$findElements(using = "css selector", "h4") #extract the h4 elements from the resumen subpage

    expediente <- unlist(elements[[1]]$getElementText())

    entidad <- unlist(elements[[8]]$getElementText())

    turno <- unlist(elements[[5]]$getElementText())

    res_text <- remDr$findElement("css selector", "#swal2-content > div > div > p")

    res_text <- unlist(res_text$getElementText())

    resumen.df$expediente[j] <- expediente

    resumen.df$entidad[j] <- entidad

    resumen.df$turno[j] <- turno

    resumen.df$res_text[j] <- res_text

#click the okay button on the page to exit the resumen subpage
    button <- remDr$findElement("css selector", "body > div.swal2-container.swal2-center.swal2-fade.swal2-shown > div > div.swal2-actions > button.swal2-confirm.swal2-styled")

    button$clickElement()

  }
```

However once I run the loop I get this error:

```
Error in elements[[1]] : subscript out of bounds
```

I assume the problem is related to how things are indexed in the loop since I can fill the data frame doing it one row at a time. Any ideas on how I can properly iterate this process?

Comment: I suggest you to put a `Sys.sleep (2)`, because you have to give time to javascript or something like that to run. Maybe you can insert the stop at the first row in the loop.

Comment: Thanks @SlowLearning I'll see if that helps. I feel like my problem might be related to another issue with the way the objects are being pulled or stored. That error I get seems to be related to the object storage.

Answer (score 0):

@SlowLearning's suggestion in the comments ultimately solved the problem but I had to add Sys.sleep(2) in a few more places to get it to work. The script was running faster than the website was loading.

```
  n <- remDr$findElement(using = "css selector", "#resultadosgsa_paginate > span > a:nth-child(7)")

  n <- n$getElementText()

  n <- as.numeric(n)

  n

for (i in 1:n) {

  # click through each page in the region, collecting the text
    res <- remDr$findElements("css selector", "#resumenResultados")

    res_n <- length(res)

    resumen.df <- data.frame(expediente = character(res_n),
                          entidad = character(res_n),
                          turno = character(res_n),
                          res_text = character(res_n),
                          stringsAsFactors = F)

    for (j in 1:res_n) {
      Sys.sleep(2)

      res[[j]]$clickElement()

      Sys.sleep(2)

      ex_location <- remDr$findElement("css selector", "#swal2-content > div > div > h4:nth-child(1)")

      expediente <- unlist(ex_location$getElementText())

      en_location <- remDr$findElement("css selector", "#swal2-content > div > div > h4:nth-child(8)")

      entidad <- unlist(en_location$getElementText())

      tu_location <- remDr$findElement("css selector", "#swal2-content > div > div > h4:nth-child(5)")

      turno <- unlist(tu_location$getElementText())

      te_location <- remDr$findElement("css selector", "#swal2-content > div > div > p")

      res_text <- unlist(te_location$getElementText())

      resumen.df$expediente[j] <- expediente

      resumen.df$entidad[j] <- entidad

      resumen.df$turno[j] <- turno

      resumen.df$res_text[j] <- res_text

      Sys.sleep(2)

      # close out the subpage and wait before opening the next one

      button <- remDr$findElement("css selector", "body > div.swal2-container.swal2-center.swal2-fade.swal2-shown > div > div.swal2-actions > button.swal2-confirm.swal2-styled")

      button$clickElement()

    }

  global.list <- list(global.df, resumen.df)
  global.df <- rbindlist(global.list)

  Sys.sleep(2)

  next.page.button <- remDr$findElement("css selector", "#resultadosgsa_next")

  next.page.button$clickElement()

  Sys.sleep(2)
}
```